# is it possible to assign one spring kafka consumer to one instance and another consumer to another instance of the same service

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

i have two kafka listeners like below:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "foo1, foo2", groupId = foo.id, id = "foo")
 public void fooTopics(@Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic, String message, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
 //processing
 }

@KafkaListener(topics = "Bar1, Bar2", groupId = bar.id, id = "bar")
 public void barTopics(@Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic, String message, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
 //processing
```

same application is running on two instances like inc1 and inc2. is there a way if i can assign foo listener to inc1 and bar listener to inc2. and if one instance is going down both the listener(foo and bar) assign to the running instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the @KafkaListener property [autoStartup](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/annotation/KafkaListener.html#autoStartup--), introduced since 2.2.
When an instance die, you can automatically start it up in the other instance like so:

```
@Autowired
private KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry;

...

@KafkaListener(topics = "foo1, foo2", groupId = foo.id, id = "foo", autoStartup = "false")
public void fooTopics(@Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic, String message, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
    //processing
}

//Start up condition
registry.getListenerContainer("foo").start();
```

Comment: thank you. but my concern is that how to force app to assign one kafka listener(foo) to one instance and another kafka listener(bar) to another instance of the same application.

Comment: Hi @Shilpi, how do you identify your instance? You can use an identifier to identify it, for example, by hostname (you can use the `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();`). So, if instance = hostname, bar container autoStartup = false, else foo container autostartUp = false. Note that autoStartup value can be assigned using property place holders  ${...}